# Using a subclass of UIViewController subclass with subclass of UIView subclass

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, subclass

I have an MVC architecture of a certain view within my app. Now I want to create a subclass of the View and Controller part. The original `UIViewController` subclass is loaded with a `UIView` subclass from storyboard. How can I make my subclass of this `UIViewController` subclass use my subclass of the UIView subclass code when it loads its view?

**EDIT**

Here's some more details about what I want to do. I currently have these classes:

```
ControlView
ControlViewController
```

which are connected with storyboard. I load an instance of ControlViewController using:

```
self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ControlViewController")! as! ControlViewController
```

Now what I want to do is subclass `ControlView` so that I can change some constraints and add a few extra subviews. Let's call this subclass `ExpandedControlView`. I also want to subclass `ControlViewController` because I want to add some extra actions from `ExpandedControlView` to the controller. This can be called `ExpandedControlViewController`.

Then I want to be able to instantiate `ExpandedControlViewController` and use `ExpandedControlView` like `ControlViewController` would with `ControlView`.

Comment: Any chance you could update your question with pseudo-code for what you want to do, maybe starting with loading the original view controller?

Comment: @PhillipMills I've added some extra details, hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard, select the hierarchy view.

[image: Select hierarchy view]

Then select your UIViewController's View in the hierarchy on the left, and select that view's class in the identity inspector on the right. [image: Hierachy View]

Or if you want to do it in code. Override viewDidLoad on ControlViewController, instantiate your custom view and set your ControlViewController's view property to your custom view.

```
-(void)loadView{
    ControlView *myCustomView = [[ControlView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
    self.view = myCustomView;
}
```

One caveat when doing this is that the layout of any subviews might change from the time loadView is called. So if you have subviews in your custom view, you should also override layoutSubviews in your custom view and set all your view's subviews' frame property again there.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Actually I've already linked the original UIView subclass in the storyboard. I'm trying to create a subclass of this UIView/UIViewController subclass. I've updated my question to try and make it a bit clearer, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Have you tried the loadView approach? If you override loadView on ControlViewController like I detailed above, then ControlViewController and it's subclass ExpandedControlViewController would both automatically use  ControlView as their view when loaded.

Comment: I'll try it! I actually want `ExpandedControlViewController` to use `ExpandedControlView` as its view, and `ControlViewController` to use `ControlView`. So I guess I'll override `loadView` in `ExpandedControlViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Implement loadView in your view controller subclass and set the view property with instance of your custom view subclass.